# Capturing SwiftUI View body self and context

Tags: swiftui

I want to implement a SwiftUI button, that accepts `onTapGesture` and `onLongPressGesture`, with an overridable handler

I have been unable to get the native button to work with both so have resorted to an `HStack`.  The buttons use the `CommandController` pattern and dispatches the command from `onTapGesture`.  The basic code was:

```
struct CmdButton : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appController : AppController
    
    var command : AppCommand

    init(command : AppCommand) {
       self.command = command

       self.onTapGesture {
         self.doCommand()
       }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(self.command.icon).resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 35)
        }
        .padding(6)
        .cornerRadius(5)
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .animation(.default)
    }
    
    func doCommand(){
        appController.dispatchCommand(command: self.command)
    }
}
```

The goal was that `CmdButton` should call `doCommand()` from `onTapGesture` by default unless it was overridden by the implementer, thus:

```
CmdButton(command: SomeCommand)
  .onTapGesture {
    doSomethingFirst()
    instance.doCommand()
  }
  .onLongPressGesture {
    doLongPressAction()
  }
```

I have 2 core issues.

There seems to be no way I can capture the correct `self` context in the `CmdButton` implementation to add the default `onTapGesture`, if I add during `init` I get the `mutating self` error.  If I add the gesture to the HStack it cannot be overridden and I can't see how to cast `some View` to a concrete type to assign directly on the `var body`.

When I override `onTapGesture` I am unable to get the `self` context of the instance in the overridden `onTapGesture` handler to call the `doCommand()` method on.

I'm aware I could pass around callbacks and attach them in the implementation, but it might pose other issues capturing context and just seems hacky for something so basic and trivial.

**EDIT**

To clarify, according Apple docs it is valid to:

```
struct MyView : View {
    let img : String = "asset"
    let name : String = "Some Name"
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(img).onTapGesture {
          onTap()
        }
    }
    
    func onTap(){
        print(name)
    }
}
```

Where the correct context is captured and the gesture handler attached to the `Image`. My question is instead of the gesture being assigned to the inner implementation how can I assign it to the outer View body so it can be overridden.

```
MyView()
  .onTapGesture {
    doSomethingElse()
    self_instance.onTap()
  }
```

Again, I can call:

```
MyView().onTap()
```

How do I get the View instance to call `onTap` inside the handler?

Comment: You try to apply OOP pro-active principles to reactive value-based SwiftUI world, so failed. Return back to SwiftUI WWDC-19 sessions.

Comment: Does the original code even work? You should be getting a warning like "Result of call to 'onTapGesture' is unused". If it does work, it's by some kind of side-effect that is almost certainly undefined behavior. Calling `.onTapGesture` doesn't modify a View. It creates a completely new View that wraps the target. So you're creating a View that responds to tap gestures and then you're just throwing it away. Your approach here isn't possible because Views are not runtime objects like UIViews; they're just data that describes the layout and behavior.

Comment: Hi Rob, no assigning `onTapGesture` in `init` is considered mutating self so can't be done.  Which is my point, how to create a default gesture handler that can be overridden and capture the correct context in this scenario.